# Limit the size of a windows 7 shared folder

Tags: windows-7

I assumed there should be an easy way to limit the size of a shared folder but I can't seem to find it? Is there some easy way to do it, preferably without 3rd party software?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do this. You can have a workaround for this by creating a virtual drive of that size, or by creating user profile that has a quota.

If you are using windows server, [here](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/configuring-volume-folder-quotas.html) is a link for how to do it in that, but it is not possible in windows 7.

Comment: http://maketecheasier.com/limit-disk-space-usage-by-users-in-windows-7/2011/02/05 I have no idea if this would be usefull or helpfull?  Does not work in Home versions.

Comment: @Psycogeek, this is a user quota, as mentioned above. It does not work on a folder level.